# Can I use "to propel sb towards their demise" as a synonym of " to kill"?

Tags: synonyms, formality

Context: I created this phrase in an attempt to paraphrase the word "kill" while doing a writing task.

I searched it up on Google and found that no one use it, therefore I do not know if its meaning is transparent or not. Anyways here is the extract of the paragraph:

> This is extremely hazardous to the elderly, whose body is already so frail and prone to illnesses, therefore even the most minor ailment can easily propel them towards their demise...

Comment: What do you mean by "formal synonym"?

Comment: If you want to combine words in an original way, that part is good. If you want to know if your wording is too fancy, it is.

Comment: Sorry for my poor choice of words, it is just synonym.

Comment: "Propelling towards their demise" sounds like someone is falling off a cliff. 'To propel sb towards their demise' sounds like they're being pushed. It's poetic, and crude, and seems completely out of place in the context.

Comment: No, it's not a synonym; it's a metaphor. An actual formal synonym of _kill_ is 'cause to die'.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of *demise* is wider than mere death:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demise)
> *demise:*
> 1a: DEATH
> b: a cessation of existence or activity
> c: a loss of position or status
> 2: the conveyance of an estate
> 3: transfer of the sovereignty to a successor

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propel)
> *propel:*
> to drive forward or onward by or as if by means of a force that imparts motion

An illness that propels to their demise is one thus reasonably understood as one that forces or imparts a motion (by analogy) towards their death (Merriam Webster meaning 1a) or any of the other instances in M-W (1b to 3). It is therefore not strictly synonymous with "kill" although that may be one of the possible consequences in the sense of Merriam Webster Meaning 1a.

Also, to *propel* towards demise is not necessarily to *arrive* at demise. This too weakens the analogy of your prose with actual death.

Briefly, your prose is consistent with killing but does not necessarily mean it.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression looks far-fetched and awkward. I would recommend the expression ***[cause death](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22can%20cause%20death%22&biw=1536&bih=722&sxsrf=ALiCzsaFOy4K8ObqJBUiHZwmjLERc2eoXw%3A1662303275706&ei=K7wUY6DlKraChbIP3KmewAs&ved=0ahUKEwjgpoeisvv5AhU2QUEAHdyUB7gQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22can%20cause%20death%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzoHCCMQsAMQJzoHCCMQsAIQJzoECAAQDUoECEEYAUoECEYYAFDKBVjDCWC9FmgBcAB4AIABZ4gB3QKSAQMzLjGYAQCgAQHIAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)***, or the adjective ***[fatal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fatal)***:

> ... therefore even the most minor ailment can easily ***cause their death/be fatal for them***.